# Firebase Permission denied in activity switch (Permission for other situations)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

When sending a Firebase request and making an activity switch at the end i get
 `DatabaseError: Permission denied` message, when running in debug mode (i.e. not letting android switch to the other activity) or replacing the `updateUI()` function to `return;` the function finishes successfully, and the data is registered in the server.

```
Button sendRequest = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bt_send_request);
sendRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(choosenLatLng == null || myTime == null){
            Toast.makeText(JobRequestActivity.this, "you need to enable location permission first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        DatabaseReference mJobDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Jobs").child("beersheva").push();
        mJobDatabase.child("costumer").setValue(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        mJobDatabase.child("date1").setValue(myTime);
        mJobDatabase.child("duration").setValue(duration.getSelectedItem());
        mJobDatabase.child("phone number").setValue("default");
        mJobDatabase.child("jobtype").setValue(jobType.name());
        mJobDatabase.child("location").setValue(new LatLng(31.246897, 34.792883));
        mJobDatabase.child("job picture").setValue("default");

        updateUI();
    }
});
private void updateUI() {
    //TODO determine where to go
    Intent intent = new Intent(JobRequestActivity.this, 
                  MainCustomerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: `DatabaseError: Permission denied` means that you're performing a read or write operation on your Firebase Database, that is not allowed by its server-side security rules.

Comment: Please show us your security rules from your Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the Permission rules, but with the fact that connection with the database is closed and reopens in activity switching.

Adding the on complete listener on the last write request fixed it

```
mJobDatabase.child("extraParams").setValue(requestValues).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(JobRequestActivity.this, "Job added to the server.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "failed adding work ", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(JobRequestActivity.this, "Could not add job, try again.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```